# The conditions under which a stress tensor $T^{\mu\nu}$ exists

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conservation-laws, conformal-field-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, locality

I used to believe that the existence of the stress tensor in a QFT has to do with translation invariance: "If a theory is translation invariant, then one can construct a conserved $T^{\mu\nu}$ by Noether theorem". But it has been pointed to me that the existence of a conserved $T^{\mu\nu}$ is related to the locality of the theory. How can we show this? and is there some counterexamples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, nonlocal CFT's like the scaling limit of long-range Ising models will typically lack a local stress tensor. In Euclidean signature, the kinetic term is $\phi (-\Delta)^{\alpha}\phi$ which is still unitary if $0<\alpha<1$.
Some references on this:

1. Paulos, M. F., Rychkov, S., van Rees, B. C., & Zan, B. (2016). [Conformal invariance in the long-range Ising model](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0550321315003703). Nuclear Physics B, 902, 246-291.
2. Behan, C., Rastelli, L., Rychkov, S., & Zan, B. (2017). [Long-range critical exponents near the short-range crossover](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.118.241601). Physical Review Letters, 118(24), 241601.
3. Behan, C., Rastelli, L., Rychkov, S., & Zan, B. (2017). [A scaling theory for the long-range to short-range crossover and an infrared duality](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1751-8121/aa8099). Journal of Physics A: Mathematical and Theoretical, 50(35), 354002.
4. Behan, C. (2019). [Bootstrapping the long-range Ising model in three dimensions](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1751-8121/aafd1b). Journal of Physics A: Mathematical and Theoretical, 52(7), 075401.

Answer (score 2):

Translation invariance guarantees only the existence of conserved charges: $P_i$ and the Hamiltonian $H$ itself. It is an extra assumption that those charges can be written in terms of local currents: $P_\mu = \int T_{0\mu}(x) d^{d-1}x$. Theories given by an action which is written in terms of local Lagrangian densities will possess a conserved EMT (provided they are translation invariant).

Comment: So is there some example of non-local theories? I've heard that theories that have terms like $\phi\Box^{19}\phi$ are not local and so they don't have an EMT.

Comment: Any positive integer power of $\Box$ will be local. On contrary, say $\phi \Box^{-1} \phi$ will be non-local

Comment: This answer lacks an argument demonstrating its correctness. I'm not asking for a proof, but for a sketch of a proof.